# How to always import a package when running Python script (non-interactive)?

Tags: python

Basically I want to replicate the behavior of `PYTHONSTARTUP` but when running a script i.e. `python app.py`. The answers I've found for this involve creating a `usercustomize.py` file and putting it in the path specified by `python -m site`.

This works to execute the script before my other script but doesn't persist any imports in that script. My goal is to always override the builtin print function with Rich when possible. So my current `PYTHONSTARTUP` file looks like this:

```
try:
    from rich import print, pretty
    pretty.install()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

If I put the above in `usercustomize.py`, it runs but the print function isn't overridden like I want it to be. It seems that is by design, but is there any way of achieving what I want some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to modify the `print` attribute of the `builtins` module. This affects all default `print(...)` calls.

```py
try:
    from rich import print, pretty
    pretty.install()
    __import__('builtins').print = print
except ImportError:
    pass
```